# How to use loop or function to simplify my program?

Tags: r, function, loops

This my code:

```
## Extract different phecode class
#1 Subset for circulatory system
circulatory_system <- per_class %>% filter(exclude_name == "circulatory system")

#2 Subset for dermatologic
dermatologic <- per_class %>% filter(exclude_name == "dermatologic")

#3 Subset for endocrine/metabolic
endocrine_metabolic <- per_class %>% filter(exclude_name == "endocrine/metabolic")

#4 Subset for genitourinary
genitourinary <- per_class %>% filter(exclude_name == "genitourinary")

#5 Subset for infectious diseases
infectious_diseases <- per_class %>% filter(exclude_name == "infectious diseases")


## List all phecode class
data_list <- list(
  circulatory_system = list(df = circulatory_system, exclude_name = "circulatory system"),
  dermatologic = list(df = dermatologic, exclude_name = "dermatologic"),
  endocrine_metabolic = list(df = endocrine_metabolic, exclude_name = "endocrine/metabolic"),
  genitourinary = list(df = genitourinary, exclude_name = "genitourinary"),
  infectious_diseases = list(df = infectious_diseases, exclude_name = "infectious diseases"),
)
```

I would like to ask if there is a more simplified way to make data_list in the same format? Because my phecode class has more than 15, it looks very messy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider base R's `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) which returns a special named list for single factor splits:

```r
data_list <- by(
  per_class, 
  per_class$exclude_name, 
  FUN = \(sub) list(df=sub, exclude_name=sub$exclude_name[1])
)
```

To adjust names of spaces and special characters for underscores:

```r
names(data_list) <- gsub(" |/", "_", names(data_list))
```

Comment: Thank you! It's very simply for my program.

Comment: Could I ask what is  function of  `\(sub)`?

Comment: The backslash  ```\``` is the new lambda symbol in R for anonymous functions. It is equivalent to `function(sub)` where `sub` (which can be named anything) is the split data frame being passed into function.

Comment: It's explain clearly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, but I would suggest to use `tidyr::nest()` if you have control over the actual data structure used for `data_list`, because it's much cleaner.

The output from `tidyr::nest()` will be a tibble with two columns, one for the column that was "pulled out" (exclude_name in your case) and df, wich is a list column containing the filtered data frames (minus the column that was pulled out).

Here is an example for all three options using the `iris` dataset and the `Species` column.

```r
data(iris)

# Option 1: Same format, but using purrr
all_species <- unique(iris$Species)
data_list1 <- purrr::set_names(all_species) |>
  purrr::map(\(species) list(
    df = iris |> dplyr::filter(Species == species),
    Species = species
  ))

# Option 2: Same format, but using base R
data_list2 <- split(iris, ~Species) |>
  lapply(\(split) list(df = split, Species = split$Species[[1L]]))

bench::mark(
  purr = purrr::set_names(all_species) |>
    purrr::map(\(species) list(
      df = iris |> dplyr::filter(Species == species),
      Species = species
    )),
  base = split(iris, ~Species) |>
    lapply(\(split) list(df = `row.names<-`(split, NULL), Species = split$Species[[1L]]))
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 purr         2.27ms   2.31ms      432.    37.9KB     12.6
#> 2 base       244.62µs 252.38µs     3946.    23.5KB     19.1

# Option 3: Slightly different format using tidyr
data_nested <- iris |>
  tidyr::nest(df = -Species)

data_nested
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   Species    df               
#>   <fct>      <list>           
#> 1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]>
#> 2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>
#> 3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]>

bench::mark(
  base = tibble::tibble(
    Species = all_species,
    df = unname(lapply(split(iris, ~Species), \(x) tibble::as_tibble(x[, -5L])))
  ),
  tidyr = iris |>
    tidyr::nest(df = -Species)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 base         1.18ms   1.21ms      825.   150.1KB     14.7
#> 2 tidyr        4.79ms   4.83ms      205.    32.5KB     13.1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I would love to know how to do the same in base R

Comment: @PesKchan Do you mean option 3? I added that to the benchmark code. Need to use `tibble::` to keep classes the same and need to manually remove the Species column from the `split()` result so the outputs are identical. A bare-bones almost equal solution would be `data.frame(Species = all_species, df = unname(split(iris, ~Species)))`

Comment: I missed that part of the code

Comment: Why do useRs overlook `by`, the forgotten member of apply family?!

Comment: Thank you! I was thought of nest function. But it is a bit difficult to understand for me. Maybe I can study it again.